# OpenCV MSER implementation produces different results for android and desktop version

Tags: android, opencv, desktop, mser

It seems like MSER algorithm works differently for desktop and Android version of OpenCV 3.0. The code below produces different results depending on the platform where OpenCV is run (desktop or android):

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
MatOfKeyPoint mokp = new MatOfKeyPoint();
FeatureDetector fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
fd.detect(img, mokp);
```

and then

```
System.out.println("Mat of key points = " + mokp.rows() + "x" + mokp.cols());
```

(for desktop) or

```
Log.i(TAG, "Mat of key points = " + mokp.rows() + "x" + mokp.cols());
```

(for android)

This is what I get in logs:

```
Mat of key points = 79x1
```

(desktop)

```
Mat of key points = 216x1
```

(android)

Why is the difference? Are there any MSER default settings, which are different for desktop and android? I'm stuck here, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - different versions of OpenCV on desktop and android. Version 3.0 is apparently using different default parameters for MSER than 3.0 RC1.

Got some hint [here.](http://answers.opencv.org/question/69185/mser-produces-different-results-for-android-and-desktop-version/)